# Async / Await method - No need to wait for method execution

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I have a async method for Send notification purpose. but i am not set await keyword while invoking the method. because no need to wait for the response to me.

But, it says, Warning.
[image]

Whether need to add await keyword to solve the Warning or ignore it?

Comment: So why do you have  it in a try catch block? Please put the code in the question and not the screenshot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use C# 7 features, assign it to "discard" variable:

```
_ = iPushNotificationService.SendPushNotification(objNotificationMessage);
```

If you can't use C# 7 - you can just assign it to some variable:

```
var t = iPushNotificationService.SendPushNotification(objNotificationMessage);
```

Or use extension method like this:

```
public static class TaskExtensions {
    public static void Ignore(this Task t) {

    }
}
```

And then:

```
iPushNotificationService.SendPushNotification(objNotificationMessage).Ignore();
```

Note that you might be not interested in result, but you might be interested if it fails to send that notification, at least to log that. In that case you can either use `ContinueWith`:

```
SendNotification().ContinueWith(c =>
{
    // do something with c.Exception
}, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted).Ignore();
```

Or move that to separate async method:

```
static async void SendNotification() { // if you hate async void - use Task
     try {
        await iPushNotificationService.SendPushNotification(objNotificationMessage);
     }
     catch (Exception ex {
         // log it
     }
}
```

And then call it.

Comment: I have tried with the above approach one by one for my another scenario which is invoking into a foreach method. but it is getting failed.

Comment: Well you need to describe in more detail, post some code and how exactly it fails. Probably better to just ask another question

Comment: My foreach method has 5 iteration. but it is failed one by one like Discard, without using await keyword while invoking, no return value.

Answer (score 1):

*You* know that this is a "fire and forget" operation and that you don't need to wait for it to return. But the compiler doesn't know that you know. As far as it's concerned, you're returning a Task (meaning you want to monitor the task progress) but not actually using it. This isn't an *error*, but it is potentially a mistake, so it's warning you. That's all.

If you want to avoid the warning, you can do anything - literally anything - with the task that will satisfy the compiler's worry that the task is being abandoned. I've written a [tiny extension method](https://gist.github.com/lisardggY/396aaca7b70da1bbc4d1640e262e990a) that does just that:

```
public static void Release(this Task task)
{
}
```

Which you can then use `iPushNotifications.SendPushNotifications(..).Release()` and the compiler will be happy.

Another alternative, less explicit but with less code, is this:

```
`iPushNotifications.SendPushNotifications(..).ContinueWith(_=>{ /* Do nothing */ });
```

**Note:** More important than silencing the compiler warnings is that it will make your code will be *explicit* about what you're doing. Another developer viewing your code won't have to guess whether you *meant* to wait for execution to complete or not.